# cypress-cucumber-preprocessor - not logging to messages.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I've been using Cypress with Cucumber for a while and somehow for some reason, it's stopped logging anything except 'testRunStarted' and 'testRunFinished' to messages.ndjson.

this is my .cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json:

```
{
  "json": {
    "enabled": true,
    "output": "cypress/cucumber-json/cucumber-json.json",
    "formatter": "cucumber-json-formatter"
  },
  "html": {
    "enabled": true,
    "output": "cypress/cucumber-html/cucumber-html.html"
  },
  "messages": {
    "enabled": true,
    "output": "cypress/messages.ndjson"
  },
  "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
  "stepDefinitions": [
    "cypress/e2e/features/*.js",
    "cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

I have ran cypress with debugging on and confirmed it's picking up the correct config, and it is writing the start and finish to messages, but nothing else.

```
{"testRunStarted":{"timestamp":{"seconds":1664439067,"nanos":940000000}}}
{"testRunFinished":{"timestamp":{"seconds":1664439137,"nanos":63000000}}}
```

Absolutely stumped on this one!

Comment: Hello Cam, I have fixed my issue by using bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor in the config. I now get messages AND json report.
Happy Days!
I will query this issue to Badeball, and see what he says. 
Refer to working project (JS) here at
 https://github.com/burakkaygusuz/cypress-cucumber-html-report-example

Answer (score 1):

I have a question: Where your step definitions are placed? Is it in the same folder where your feature files exists or they are found in support folder? Wherever it present just use that path in your `step_definitions` in `.cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json`.

So your `.cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json` should look like this if your step definitions are in `support` folder

```
{
  "json": {
    "enabled": true,
    "output": "cypress/cucumber-json/cucumber-json.json",
    "formatter": "cucumber-json-formatter"
  },
  "html": {
    "enabled": true,
    "output": "cypress/cucumber-html/cucumber-html.html"
  },
  "messages": {
    "enabled": true,
    "output": "cypress/messages.ndjson"
  },
  "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
  "stepDefinitions":
    "cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*{.js,.mjs}"
}
```

Hope you will get your results.

Comment: @Cam - Are you able to view the data in messages.ndjson? I'm also facing a similar issue after I cloned the boiler plate code from here - https://github.com/JoanEsquivel/cypress-cucumber-boilerplate. I've followed all the steps correctly, as mentioned in the boiler plate on a windows machine, with the json formatter for a windows machine, but the log.json file is always empty.

Comment: @Vishal Can you confirm that in your windows PATH, you can see `cucumber-json-formatter.exe`? or are you able to run `cucumber-json-formatter --help`? If its not a case than please refer this repo, its required:
https://github.com/cucumber/json-formatter

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Windows machine and have the right cucumber-json-formatter.exe. By windows PATH, I believe you're referring to the project folder path?

Comment: Thanks Vishal & Uzair, My project isn't generating messages.ndjson at all :/

Comment: I've removed the unnecessary path to the features file and ensured stepDefinitions is correct. Still not having any luck! Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

PATH is an environment variable, not your project folder path.
Run the command echo $PATH in order to see a list of paths that are eligible for you to put the cucumber-json-formatter.exe into.

If you don't want to put this file in your path, you can use the json.formatter property in your config to point at this exe file.

Config to point at the formatter:
https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/json-report.md

Where to find the formatter:
https://github.com/cucumber/json-formatter